# How can I change response status in void method (not returning ResponseEntity)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use Java 11 und Spring.

Let's assume I have a method like this:

```
  @POST
  @Path(WebservicePaths.EXAMPLE_PATH)
  public void processData(@NotNull @RequestBody TypeOfRequest request) {
       try {
            doSomething(request);
           }
        catch(Exception e) {
            ?????????????
        }
  }
```

At this moment the HTTP response is set automatically, right?

1. How can I get und print to the console body of the final response?
2. How can I change response status or other details to specific one only in block catch() {}?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `HttpServletResponse` and can call `sendError` method and pass the required `HttpStatus` in it. Below is the example:

```
@POST
@Path(WebservicePaths.EXAMPLE_PATH)
public void processData(@NotNull @RequestBody TypeOfRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
   try {
        doSomething(request);
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
      response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
   }
}
```